# Does $F$ being an extreme ray of a convex set $C$ imply that the direction of $F$ is in the recession cone?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, polyhedra, convex-cone

Let $C$ be a convex set, and let $F=x+\mathbb{R}^+_0s$, $s\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, be a facet of $C$, that is, an extreme ray. Does this imply $s$ being an element of the recession cone, i.e., is $$y+\mathbb{R}^+_0s\subseteq C,\quad y\in C?$$
If yes, how do I show it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's wrong.  Take $C = \{(x,y) ~ | ~ y> 0   \} \cup \{(0,0)\}$

Comment: how about if C is closed and convex?

Comment: @Lennart  if $C$ is either open or closed , then it is true .